# jQuery Countdown Timer is not displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

Have create a countdown timer by using jQuery. Hence, the countdown timer will only be activated after the user has navigated from the previous page to the current page. Therefore, in the current page, the blocks that are to be displayed will be

1.) Countdown Timer
2.) Scroll roller

***Issue:***

the Scroll roller is able to be displayed, however not the countdown Timer. What have I done wrong.

Code:

```js
 var count = 5;

 function updateTimer() {
   if (count > 0) {
     $("#content").fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $("#content").text(count);
       $("#content").fadeIn();
       count--;
     });

   } else if (count == 0) {
     $("#content").fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $("#content").text("Start!");
       $("#content").fadeIn();
       count--;
       /*To display the canvas and countDown() function in 2 sec interval
       after the fadein countdown is completed
       */
       setTimeout(function() {
         //canvasFunction();


         //TEST: Countdown Gauge   
         (function($) {
           var settings;
           var timer;
           var circleSeconds;
           var layerSeconds;

           var element;
           var callbackFunction;

           $.fn.final_countdown = function(options, callback) {
             element = $(this);

             // Element is not visibile
             if (!element.is(':visible')) {
               return;
             }

             var defaults = $.extend({
               start: undefined,
               end: undefined,
               now: undefined,
               selectors: {
                 value_seconds: '.clock-seconds .val',
                 canvas_seconds: 'canvas-seconds'
               },
               seconds: {
                 borderColor: '#654321',
                 borderWidth: '6'
               },
             }, options);

             settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

             if (settings.start === undefined) {
               settings.start = element.data('start');
             }

             if (settings.end === undefined) {
               settings.end = element.data('end');
             }

             if (settings.now === undefined) {
               settings.now = element.data('now');
             }

             if (element.data('border-color')) {
               settings.seconds.borderColor = element.data('border-color');
             }

             if (settings.now < settings.start) {
               settings.start = settings.now;
               settings.end = settings.now;
             }

             if (settings.now > settings.end) {
               settings.start = settings.now;
               settings.end = settings.now;
             }

             if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
               callbackFunction = callback;
             }

             responsive();
             dispatchTimer();
             prepareCounters();
             startCounters();
           };

           function responsive() {
             $(window).load(updateCircles);

             $(window).on('redraw', function() {
               switched = false;
               updateCircles();
             });
             $(window).on('resize', updateCircles);
           }

           function updateCircles() {
             layerSeconds.draw();
           }

           function convertToDeg(degree) {
             return (Math.PI / 180) * degree - (Math.PI / 180) * 90
           }

           function dispatchTimer() {
             timer = {
               total: Math.floor((settings.end - settings.start) / 86400),
               seconds: 60 - Math.floor((((settings.end - settings.now) % 86400) % 3600) % 60)
             }
           }

           function prepareCounters() {
             // Seconds
             var seconds_width = $('#' + settings.selectors.canvas_seconds).width()
             var secondsStage = new Kinetic.Stage({
               container: settings.selectors.canvas_seconds,
               width: seconds_width,
               height: seconds_width
             });

             circleSeconds = new Kinetic.Shape({
               drawFunc: function(context) {
                 var seconds_width = $('#' + settings.selectors.canvas_seconds).width()
                 var radius = seconds_width / 2 - settings.seconds.borderWidth / 2;
                 var x = seconds_width / 2;
                 var y = seconds_width / 2;

                 context.beginPath();
                 context.arc(x, y, radius, convertToDeg(0), convertToDeg(timer.seconds * 6));
                 context.fillStrokeShape(this);

                 $(settings.selectors.value_seconds).html(10 - timer.seconds);
               },
               stroke: settings.seconds.borderColor,
               strokeWidth: settings.seconds.borderWidth
             });

             layerSeconds = new Kinetic.Layer();
             layerSeconds.add(circleSeconds);
             secondsStage.add(layerSeconds);
           }

           function startCounters() {
             //var timer.seconds = 10;

             var interval = setInterval(function() {

               if (timer.seconds > 11) {
                 if (10 - timer.minutes == 0) {
                   clearInterval(interval);
                   if (callbackFunction !== undefined) {
                     callbackFunction.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
                   }
                   return;
                 }

                 timer.seconds = 0;

               } else {
                 timer.seconds++;
               }

               layerSeconds.draw();
             }, 1000);
           }
         })(jQuery);
         //TEST


         $("#UserInteraction").show();
         //countDown();   
       }, 2000)
     });
     $("#content").fadeOut();
   } else {
     $("#content").fadeOut();
     clearInterval(interval);
   }
 }
 setInterval(function() {
   updateTimer()
 }, 2000);
```

```css
  .countdown-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .clock-item .inner {
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .clock-canvas {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
  }
  .text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    width: 100%;
  }
  .text .val {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .text .type-time {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .clock-item {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .clock-item {
      margin: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="page2" class="img-wrapper" align="center" style=" position: relative; background-image: url(Image/Page2.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%;height: 100%;">

  <div id='content'></div>
  <!-- <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
            </canvas>
            <canvas id="Counter" width="300" height="300">
            </canvas>-->
  <div id="scroller">
    <p id="scrollTopId"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="UserInteraction" style="display:none" z-index="2">
    <img id="roller" style="position: relative; top:1100px; width: 100%" src="image/rolling_pin/Rolling_Pin_Spin000.png" />
    <img id="scroll" style="position:absolute; top: 1250px; left: 380px; overflow-y: auto;" src="image/Scroll.png">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to look what is going on, but there are images missing, can you provide a full file path to the images (http://www.yoursite.com/Image/rolling_pin/Rolling.....) Important: never use filenames with spaces in them 'Rolling Pin Spin000.png' rename the image to something like this: Rolling_Pin_Spin000.png or RollingPinSpin000.png - also, try to use only lowercase characters - so not 'Image' but 'image' to avoid confusion.

Comment: @TobiasBeuving alright, I have edited the filenames. Secondly, the path is this : Documents/Projects/image/rolling_pin/Rolling_Pin_Spin000.png. I am currently using images from file directories.

Comment: I mean - can you put the images on a server so we can access them and see what is going on

Comment: @TobiasBeuving Thanks for trying to help!!I have solved it!=)

Comment: No problem0, great that you solved it! :-) Good luck with your project, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have `display:none` on the root div `page2`:

```
<div id="page2" class="img-wrapper" align="center" style=" position: relative; background-image: url(Image/Page2.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; width: 100%;height: 100%;">
```

Remove `display:none` or set it to `display:block`

https://jsfiddle.net/kebw53ue/1/

Comment: I have set the following display: none is so that page 2 will not enroach into page 1 when page 1 is on display. Hence, I have set id = page 2 as z-index=2, so that page 2 is a stack and will be place above page 1 only when id =page2 is called

Comment: So you are removing its display:none elsewhere in your code then? Because I can't see where it's done in the JS above.

Comment: I have set the following display: none is so that page 2 will not enroach into page 1 when page 1 is on display. Hence, I have set id = page 2 as z-index=2, so that page 2 is a stack and will be place above page 1 only when id =page2 is called. As stated in the problem; I was able to display the 2 image blocks but not the countdown timer. I reckon that if the display: none is an issue, it shouldnt be displaying anything at all. right?

Comment: I have display: none in my other code. cause I have set each div to be of z-index:n, where n is stack no of the div tag. And in my script tag, I have set a condition to allow this: ("$page1").hide();("$page2").show(). this is why I set all my other pages to have display: none

Comment: OK, But in my JSFiddle I can see it counting down from 5 after I changed to display:block.

Comment: correct!!cause this is only display page. Apologies, I forgot to change that display: block when I upload the question